# How do I exit a fragment and return to my drawer activity using the back button?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to make an app which has the `DrawerActivity` as the main activity. I have implemented 8 fragments within it, which correspond to each item in the drawer. Now, the problem I have is, whenever I try to press the back button to go back to the `DrawerActivity` from the fragment, I end up exiting the app instead. I've been searching on forums for three days now, and have not found any solution to this. Quite frustrated, I stupidly deleted my code, so I can't really show it right now. Can anyone simply explain to me how I should exit a fragment using the back button, and return to my main activity?

Current scenario:
`DrawerActivity` contains eight fragments, all independent of each other. Let's call them fragments A through H. When I go to fragment A, I should be able to open the `navigationDrawer` and head to any other fragments from B to H. However, on pressing the back button, I should also be able to go back to the drawer activity's main page.

Things I have tried which didn't work are
1. Using onBackPressed and popBackStack.
2. Creating custom listener.
3. Using fragmentTransaction.

Comment: By `to go back to the drawer activity's main page` you mean going back to the first fragment or to the activity?

Comment: I mean to go back to the activity, because the fragment is part of the activity, right? For example, if I have "HELLO" displayed on the page of the activity, then i go to the fragment, and press back, I should be able to see "HELLO" again.

Comment: @CannonBaller9Pin Did you define the "HELLO" TextView (or whatever View you use to display the text) in an xml file?

Comment: @M.S. I just used "HELLO" as an example. Suppose my main activity is blank. It contains three fragments launched from three options in the drawer. Suppose I click on the first option. Now, I press the back button. Instead of quitting the app directly, I want to go back to the first page displayed by the app, i.e. the blank main activity page.

Comment: @CannonBaller9Pin Could it be that you would like to detach the Fragment or to remove it?

Comment: @M.S. Thanks for your interest in my question. I figured it out, though. It is really a stupid mistake on my part. I've answered it below, and I can't believe I made such a blunder without thinking it through.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe how stupid I am. I was using my Gmail app on my phone when I suddenly realized that the first fragment in the drawer activity is always the default fragment, and the app should always revert to it on the back button press. What I was thinking was that the drawer activity would go back to the original state when back is pressed, but I didn't account for the fact that fragments are part of the activity itself.
Thank you all for trying to understand my problem, which wasn't really a problem at all... It seems I learned something in spite of myself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding onBackPressed() without calling the superclass method? (So that you prevent finish() from being called.)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //show Fragment A
}
```

Call it without the "super.onBackPressed()" and it should work.

Comment: I don't want to go back to another fragment from my current fragment. I want to go back to the activity which launched the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You must add your fragment to the android back Stack like this:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.your_container,fragment,fragment.TAG)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```